# android : How to freeze single row when create excel sheet from sqlite database android

Tags: android, excel

```html
this is my output in excel by android

id       name        buymilk       price
 1        ashish       5lt          100rs 
 2       anil          4lt          80rs
 3       jhon          10lt         200rs
 4      total price
        is 380rs for 
           19lt.


but i want my output in excel like

id       name        buymilk       price
 1        ashish       5lt          100rs 
 2       anil          4lt          80rs
 3       jhon          10lt         200rs

 4      total price is 380rs for 19lt.
```

`

4      total price is 380rs for 19lt.
`

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);//create excel
bw.newline();
```

**My output is like this:**

[image: word wrapped in one cell]

**But I want it like this:**

[image: merged and centred cell]

Comment: embedded images inline and formatted code

Comment: how to create in android bro